# WebStorm finding references but Browser isn't - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am building a game using Phaser and I'm organizing my code into separate models:

```
main.js
Models:
    -Player.js
    -Enemy.js
    -Powers.js
```

When I go to implement them, WebStorm (the IDE I'm using) autocompletes, so I know it's finding the definition of the reference.

In main.js I call:

```
wzrd = Player.CreatePlayer();
```

In the above example, WebStorm found both the `Player` object and the `CreatePlayer` method, however when I go to test the code in my browser, Firebug throws the error:

```
ReferenceError: Player is not defined
```

My Player.js file:

```
Player = {};

Player.CreatePlayer = function() {
    var wzrd = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'chars');
    this.EquipPlayer();
    game.physics.arcade.enable(wzrd);
    wzrd.frame = 10;
    wzrd.animations.add('left', [21,22,23,22], 5, true);
    wzrd.animations.add('right', [33,34,35,34], 5, true);
    wzrd.body.gravity.y = 500;
    wzrd.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    game.camera.follow(wzrd);

    return wzrd;
};

Player.EquipPlayer = function() {
    flame = game.add.sprite(wzrd.position.x, wzrd.position.y-15, 'flame');
    flame.animations.add('fireRight', [32,33,34,35,36,37,39], 20, true);
    flame.animations.add('fireLeft', [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 20, true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly call: `game.load.script('Powers.js', './models/Powers.js');` in the `preload` function